# how to declare multiple groups in XSD?

Tags: xsd

In my scenario my **XSD** should have multiple groups under one root tag,
    #XSD#

```
<xs:group name="location">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="flat_num" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="landmark" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="student">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="mothername" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="fathername" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="Student_details" type="details"/>

<xs:complexType name="details">
  <xs:group ref="location"/>
  <xs:group ref="student"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

When i am validating with xml , it says this format is wrong , 
can any one help to let me know how to create multiple groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your missing the Sequence in the complex type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2017 - Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7089 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:group name="location">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="flat_num" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="landmark" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="student">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="mothername" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="fathername" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:element name="Student_details" type="details" />
    <xs:complexType name="details">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:group ref="location" />
            <xs:group ref="student" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]

I would also question whether a group best implements what you are trying to describe. What you have currently will produce XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2017 - Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7089 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<Student_details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Schema.xsd">
    <city>string</city>
    <flat_num>string</flat_num>
    <landmark>string</landmark>
    <street>string</street>
    <firstname>string</firstname>
    <lastname>string</lastname>
    <mothername>string</mothername>
    <fathername>string</fathername>
</Student_details>
```

Comment: It is working thanks , in my scenario how to set location group elements as non-mandatory and student group as mandatory elements.

Comment: <xs:group minOccurs="0" ref="location" />